How can I use index and match two way lookup
I need a formula that add the nurses name from column F into Colum D if they have that room (G3 to K7)
For example: Nurse A currently have room 2101, 2108, 2155, 2165 so her name should be displayed in the specific room row.




Room
Patient Name/Age
Code
Nurse




2101

Full



2102

Full



2103

Full



2104

FC



2105





2106

Full



2107





2108

Full



2109

Full



2110

Full



2151

Full



2152





2153

Full



2154

Full



2155

FC



2156

Full



2157

Full



2161

Full



2162

Full



2163





2164










Nurse
Room 1
Room 2
Room 3
Room 4
Room 5




A
2101
2108
2155
2165



B
2102
2109
2156
2166



C
2103
2110
2157
2167



D
2104
2151
2161
2168



E
2105
2152
2162
2169



F
2106
2153
2163
2170



G
2107
2154
2164
2170




Sheet Picture
I used the following =IF(A3=H3,F3,"") and it did the trick but just for one cell. I tried multiple cells and ended up breaking the sheet.

=IF(COUNTIF($G$3:$K$7, A3) > 0, INDEX($F$3:$F$7, MATCH(TRUE, INDEX($G$3:$K$7=A3, 0), 0)), "")
try using this formula at d3 to handle 2 way lookup

Try using anyone of the following formulas per your preferences:


• Using IFS() + TOCOL()
=TOCOL(IFS(A3=G$3:K$9,F$3:F$9),2)


• Or, Using REPT() + CONCAT()
=CONCAT(REPT(F$3:F$9,G$3:K$9=A3))


• Using MAP() + TOCOL() + IFS() to return for the whole range as an array output.
=MAP(A3:A23,LAMBDA(x,TOCOL(IFS(G3:K9=x,F3:F9),2)))


• Or, Older Versions -- using INDEX()+AGGREGATE()+IFERROR():
=IFERROR(INDEX(F$3:F$9,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(F$3:F$9)-ROW(F$3)+1)/(G$3:K$9=A3),1)),"")


• Or, ETA LAMBDA() using FILTER()+BYROW()+OR()
=FILTER(F$3:F$9,BYROW(G$3:K$9=A3,OR),"")


• Or, Using MAP()+ETA LAMBDA() --> BYROW()+FILTER()+OR()
=MAP(A3:A23,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(F3:F9,BYROW(G3:K9=x,OR),"")))


• Or Using MMULT() + FILTER()
=FILTER(F$3:F$9,MMULT(N(G$3:K$9=A3),TOCOL(--RIGHT(G$2:K$2))^0),"")


Shared the possible ways, as one can return the output in many ways, the above outlined solutions, gives an idea about the concept on arrays as well helps to learn.


Awesome! This is very helpful.
